# How to remove duplicates values in a matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, duplicates

How can I remove duplicates values in a matrix?

```py
mat = [[5,6,8] , [8,5,3] , [9,10,3]]
res= []
for i in mat:
    if i not in res:
        res.append(i)
        print(res)
        fit= set(res)
        print(fit)
```

Comment: expected output ?

Answer (score 3):

```
mat = [[5,6,8] , [8,5,3] , [9,10,3]]
res=[]
for i in mat:
    res+=i
duplicated= set([i for i in res if res.count(i)>1])
new=[]
for i in mat:
    new_in=[]
    for j,val in enumerate(i):
        if val not in duplicated:
            new_in.append(val)
    new.append(new_in)
print(new)
```

If you are expected your output like [[6], [], [9, 10]]

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting your output as **{3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10}**, it removes duplicate values then simple below code you can use

```
mat = [[5,6,8] , [8,5,3] , [9,10,3]]
res= set()
for i in mat:
  res.update(i)
print(res)
```

Comment: @vaibhavanayan  i want o/p in list format not in dict

Comment: @vijayaLakshmi since you didn't mention the expected o/p in your question I referred your code for o/p. And if you want in **list** format, just convert it in list using `list`. Exp: `print(list(res))` instead of `print(res)`. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @vaibhavanayan  yah its my mistake and it is helps thanks

Comment: @vijayaLakshmi Welcome. Consider to accept one answer please.